# Stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures. Please provide me help. Later I will write be myself and i have written only few logic here. I have two tables `Call_Match` and `Subs_Info`. Columns and datatype information are shown below.

I have to write a stored procedure and the logic should be:

- SP input : Number -> callNumber
- SP output : varchar -> ReturnString ( comma delimited )
- SP output : Number -> ErrorCode
- Logic : callNumber pattern will check against Call_Match table column TextPattern. if it matches callNumber equality will check against SUBS_INFO table CALL_NO column. In return string all the values should be comma separated.
- Return :  DRR, NO_TIME, CFU , NRC

Table: `Call_Match`

Columns :

- TextPattern ( varchar2 ): 0112
- DRR ( Number) : 5
- NO_TIME ( Number ) : 1

Table: `SUBS_INFO`

Columns:

- CALL_NO (varchar2 ) : 01121213
- CFU (Number): 1
- NRC ( Number ) : 3

Comment: please help anyone. if question is not clear then please let me know.

Comment: is this a homework ? have you tried to do anything ?

Comment: @ Moudiz : I tried it little bit. create or replace
PROCEDURE EXECUTE_DATA
(
   CALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
   RETURN_RESULT OUT VARCHAR2,
   ERROR_CODE OUT INTEGER
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN CURSOR_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM Call_Match where TextPattern  like CALL_NUMBER%;
     
END;

Comment: but as i am new so not able to write and think. I have to write so much logic. If you help me then i can other logic myself

Comment: ok very good added it in your question and ill try to help you

Comment: @ Moudiz : Actually there are so many others columns as well in both the tables. Its bit tough and time taking to write about all the columns ( around 45 columns ).

Comment: @Moudiz : please help me as per the current logic available in the question.

Comment: okay correct me if I am wrong you want to check column textpattern of table call_match  if it matches callnumber then it will check table subs_info with column call_no .. then what ? you want to return result of table subs_info ? and from where do you read callNumber ?

Comment: you want to check column textpattern of table call_match if it matches callnumber then it will check table subs_info with column call_no, if it matches will will return comma delimited string with values DRR, NO_TIME, CFU , NRC. Else return 0 error code. callNumber will come as a input from java code

Comment: @Moudiz :  Waiting for your reply

Comment: i am doing it give some time :)

Comment: @Moudiz : What happen ?

Comment: ITs a simple procedure of what I understand from you, I didnt add a cursor or anything , maybe I undersatand thelogic wrong. check it please if you need to add anything in it tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are anything missing tell me about it , it still need handeling error.

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE EXECUTE_DATA 
( CALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2, RETURN_RESULT OUT VARCHAR2, ERROR_CODE OUT INTEGER )
 AS
 VAR_DRR NUMBER(3);
VAR_NO_TIME NUMBER(3) ;
VAR_CFU NUMBER(3);
VAR_NRC NUMBER(3);
CNT NUMBER(3);
CNT1 NUMBER(3);
 BEGIN 
-- check if there are values equale to call number;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM CALL_MATCH WHERE TEXTPATTERN =CALL_NUMBER;
IF CNT >0 THEN
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT1 FROM SUBS_INFO WHERE CALL_NO =CALL_NUMBER;
end if;
-- check if there are values in the another table;
IF CNT1 >0 THEN
SELECT CALL_MATCH.DRR ,CALL_MATCH.NO_TIME ,SUBS_INFO.CFU ,SUBS_INFO.NRC 
INTO VAR_DRR ,VAR_NO_TIME , VAR_CFU,VAR_NRC
FROM CALL_MATCH,SUBS_INFO WHERE 
CALL_MATCH.TEXTPATTERN =CALL_NUMBER
 and SUBS_INFO.CALL_NO =CALL_NUMBER; -- its better to have a kind of checking, this is example

-- the returning result that you want
RETURN_RESULT:= VAR_DRR||','||VAR_NO_TIME||','||VAR_CFU||','||VAR_NRC;
ELSE 
RETURN_RESULT :=NULL;

end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and I will get back to you on this

Comment: @ Moudiz : Thanks It worked. As you mentioned that you have not used Cursor. Why we need to use cursor here.